# NSString in NSMutableArray isn't the same on myString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I have a problem with `NSString` and `NSMutableArray`.
When I retrieve a string from mutable array ,it has more white spaces, and I don't understand why it's happening.

I'll explain, I have an array and populate it by query (using sqlite3):

```
NSMutableArray *fileNameAttached = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:query]];
```

and it's like this:

```
<__NSArrayM 0x15e233980>(
<__NSArrayM 0x15e26afd0>(
Allegato N. 1
)

)
```

When I retrieve the string Allegato N.1 with this code:

```
NSString *test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [fileNameAttached objectAtIndex:0] ];
```

string test is like this:

```
(
    "Allegato N. 1"
)
```

Why my string isn't only:

```
Allegato N.1
```

When I put it in a label it's not correct because contains () and white spaces.
The query for DB is:

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT fileName FROM Attach WHERE ID = '%@';",ticketID];
```

and works perfectly,in fact when I populate tableview cell it's OK. But I don't understand because my string test contains 3 line with more white spaces.

Please help Me.

Thank you and sorry for my english.

Comment: According to your log: it seems that it's a NSArray of NSArray of NSString.
So `NSString *test = [[fileNameAttached objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0];`, but that may point out an issue elsewhere (format/fetch wrong)

Comment: I try your solution and it's work perfectly. Thanks, can you explain me because my array is NSArray of NSArray...Where i  did mistake??
Thank you very much

Comment: Without the code of your fetch, we can't guess. But if your query (in case they are various results) is to give a NSArray of NSArray of NSString, it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your log there are two arrays.

`( 
(
  Allegato N. 1
)
)`

There are two round brackets thats means two array.

You are fetching data like `NSString *test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [fileNameAttached objectAtIndex:0] ];`

That means first object of outer array so it is another array. so you need to do something like

```
NSArray *temp =[fileNameAttached objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [temp objectAtIndex:0] ];
```

`I think you are using appcoda's DBManager class to do this. If it is so then you everytime got two array when load query.`

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Yes i used appcoda's DBManager class. Therefore how can i extract NSArray from NSArray or how can i solve this in DBManager class??
Thank you so much

Comment: You not need to solve anything. You just got array of array everytime so you can parse it as i mentioned in answer.